# HighCharts Error bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

In the example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/error-bar/

```
series: [{
    name: 'Rainfall',
    type: 'column',
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '<span style="font-weight: bold; color: {series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b> '
    }}, 
    {
        name: 'Rainfall error',
        type: 'errorbar',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [[48, 51], [68, 73], [92, 110], [128, 136], [140, 150], [171, 179], [135, 143], [142, 149], [204, 220], [189, 199], [95, 110], [52, 56]],
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '(error range: {point.low}-{point.high} mm)<br/>'
        }
    },
```

My question is how to pass some dynamic data to the errorbar type figure, e.g. the data returned from REST API call.

I was trying to pass in chartData.stddevs constructed below to the "data" field but failed.

```
function loadchart() {
    // Convert the chart data into chart understandable format.
    var chartData = {
        ......
        stddevs: $.map(trendData(), function (obj, i) {
            return [[0.9*parseFloat(obj.Cost()),1.1*parseFloat(obj.Cost())]];
        }),
        ......
}
```

Comment: Is your dynamic data a new series? Updates to an old series? Sounds like something for `Chart.addSeries` or `Series.update`.

Comment: No. what I am trying to realize is one data series returned from some web method call and apply errorbar to each data point. The lower and upper error bound of each data point is -/+10% of each data point value.

Comment: So you will get the json with Ajax, and then add a new series which is of the type errorbar...? I'm still not seeing how that is different from what I said. Errorbar is not a part of a line series. It is a separate series.